# Авторизация VK через Java

Tags: java, вконтакте, авторизация

Идея такова: я пытаюсь сделать приложение на Java которое будет видеть друзей указанного пользователя. Но так как без авторизации ВК не показывает друзей пользователя, мне нужно авторизоваться, получить какие то данные об авторизации, а затем с этими данными послать запрос поиска по пользователям. Как можно такое осуществить? Смотрел Vk Api,  но там судя по всему просто используются данные входящего человека.

Я новичок в Java и программирования в общем, так что прошу немного понимания :)

Comment: Почему бы не попытаться загуглить - "vk api java". Первая ссылка в которой разжёвывает человек на хабре - https://habrahabr.ru/post/144813/ В чём соль вопроса?

Comment: @VictorPerov программа с хабра не работает, так как устраела.

Comment: Первым делом - смотрим документацию по VK API на сайте. Там есть примеры. Раздел "Разработчикам".

Answer (score 1):

VK использует протокол `OAuth 2` для авторизации, следовательно тебе надо искать java-реализацию клиента этого протокола. Советую присмотреться к [pac4j](http://www.pac4j.org/authenticatewithfacebooktwittergooglein5minutes.html). В нём есть средства для быстрой интеграции. Но всё же настоятельно рекомендую сначала изучить, как работает `OAuth 2.0`